# knpMenuBundle symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4, knpmenubundle

I try use knpMenuBundle in symfony 4

I render 
 {{ knp_menu_render('App:MenuBuilder:menuTags') }}

class is in src/ 
App\Menu\MenuBuilder

get

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Bundle "App" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file?").
```

Second i try use it as service -

```
{{ knp_menu_render('App\Menu\Builder:menuTags') }}
```

dont work...

i can inject this auto register service to other controller .

i read in packagist -

```
KnpMenuBundle v2.2.1
require:
symfony/framework-bundle: ~2.7|~3.0 | ^4.0
```

so it should work - in official symfony Documentation any information about symfony 4

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/menu_service.html

I think remove APpBundle was a stupid way...

Any idea how i can use MenuBuilder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use this "{{knp_menu_render ('App \ Menu \ Builder: menuTags')}}" to service. Use the alias of the service you created.

With Symfony 4 you need to use the menus as a service.

Try it out.

```
{{ knp_menu_render ('main') }}
```

Comment: It's a shame, but I understand - maybe in symfony 5 we get back AppBundle or similar links - like app:class:method now phpstorm dont understand {{ knp_menu_render ('main') }} and main is not link

Comment: I wrote a simple and handy menu system for Symfony 4. I advise you to review. https://github.com/rmznpydn/pd-menu